# Fade in popup on page load

Tags: javascript, popup

I have the following  code  which shows  a  popup on page  load  and then automatically closes it.

```
<script>
    function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
        if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
        else document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        
        setTimeout(function () {
            PopUp('show');
        }, 000);
    }
    // Disappears after set interval...
    setInterval(function(){
    $('#ac-wrapper').hide();
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

How can I make the popup gradually fade in on load, and fade out on timeout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using JQuery. In this case you may use this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  $('#ac-wrapper')
    .fadeIn(100)
    .delay(3000)
    .fadeOut(100);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Maxim, works like a charm. Very best wishes to you.